why is all this swap space being used?
I have a Debian box, where I am doing some data recovery using ddrescue on a sata ssd. The process has been running for 24 hours, and has 24 to go (at least)
in any event, the PC has 16GB ram, and 10GB swap. For some reason, There is 8GB swap in use, and 2GB RAM in use. This seems like an inefficient use of resources. I'd like to avoid this behavior in the future. Why is the memory devices being utilized in this way?
And what can be done to avoid this sort of operation in the future?

Is this really swap or is this "zram" / "zswap", i.e., compressed memory contents?

Disable disk swap completely, as I've been doing since 2000 or so. It's a relic of the past and generally must not be used unless you understand why you absolutely need it. Most people with enough RAM do not. And for SSD/NVMe storage it's outright bad.

Swap is being used instead of ram because the memory pushed to swap was inactive, not being used, and likely your ddrescue is pulling in a lot of data that is filling up cache in ram.
This is not really an efficiency problem, it should be able to pull the data out of swap fairly quickly when it needs it.  It is in swap because the system thinks growing cache is a better use of the ram.  Generally this is true, but ddrescue is probably going to use those disk blocks only once anyway.
This is a mostly harmless situation, but if it really bothers you, you could create a cgroup, move ddrescue into it, and then update the memory.max parameter for that cgroup to limit how much ram ddrescue can use.
Note that if ddrescue is rereading the blocks more than once, this could potentially make it much slower.  And if it is not, changing this parameter will not make the rest of the system significantly faster, as if the pages that are swapped out were being used, they would not have been swapped out.

when it finishes in 14  hours (hopefully), Ill check that out. I've never seen this happen before, I was just curious.

One uses swap space to control what happens when programs allocate all the real memory, and want more. After all releasable cache (some cached blocks are "in use", and cannot be freed) has been released, the system enters the Out-Of-Memory state. In the Out-Of-Memory condition, with swap, some task's memory is written to disk, freed for reuse, and later  returned to memory (swapped in) when the task runs. Without swap, the system may freeze,  the dreaded OOM-Killer (a pseudo process, hard-coded in the kernel) runs, and picks a process to KILL, in order to free memory. The OOM-Killer is known for inconvenient choices.

Swap isn’t used after all reclaimable cache has been reclaimed; it’s a balance. Generally, pages that haven’t been used for a long time are swapped out in preference to reclaiming cache.

That is the opposite of what is happening. Its no where near using all the available ram. Im not trying to get rid of swap space, but the current usage seems disproportionate. I mean, lets say it wanted to use 10GB Ram, of 16GB, thats not going to trigger OOM. or at least it shouldnt. I've run modeling simulations with 6 billion calculations, using 15 of 16GB ram use, and only had some minor lag. I dont understand why the utilization is so bad here.
